# Service broker with activation procedure error

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, stored-procedures, service-broker

I create a target queue to receive message in sql server using service broker .My target queue is like this :

```
USE [DatabaseB]
GO

ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[TargetQueue] WITH STATUS = OFF , RETENTION = OFF , ACTIVATION (  STATUS = ON , PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[myp] , MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 10 , EXECUTE AS N'dbo'  ), POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = ON)
```

Here is my store procedure that i call when the message is received in target_queue

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myp]

```
AS   


WHILE (1=1)
  BEGIN

  Declare @ConversationHandle as uniqueidentifier
Declare @MessageBody as nvarchar(max)
Declare @MessageType as sysname

Begin Transaction
Print 'Started Receiving ';

RECEIVE top (1)
      @MessageType = message_type_name,
      @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
    @MessageBody = message_body
FROM TargetQueue;

if @MessageType = 'SenderMessageType'
      Begin
            SEND 
                  ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
                  Message Type ReceiverMessageType
                  ('Message is received')
            END Conversation @ConversationHandle
            insert into table_1 (dataa)  values ('salam')
      END

Commit


  end
```

But when the message is received by the queue my store procedure adds unlimited data to `table_1` but i have a condition as you can see above ,i mean for each message that is received the sp should add one row to table not unlimited rows .Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change the store procedure to this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myp]

AS   


WHILE (1=1)
  BEGIN

  Declare @ConversationHandle as uniqueidentifier
Declare @MessageBody as nvarchar(max)
Declare @MessageType as sysname

Begin Transaction
Print 'Started Receiving ';
 WAITFOR
    (
RECEIVE top (1)
      @MessageType = message_type_name,
      @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
    @MessageBody = message_body
FROM TargetQueue), TIMEOUT 5000;
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      BREAK;
    END

if @MessageType = 'SenderMessageType'
      Begin
            SEND 
                  ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
                  Message Type ReceiverMessageType
                  ('Message is received')
            END Conversation @ConversationHandle
            insert into table_12 (dataa)  values ('salam')
      END

Commit


  end
```